# Insert element in list python

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, append

Why this code:

```
result_list = [[]]*14
result_list[3].append('sdfda')
print(result_list)
```

is output:

```
[['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda'], ['sdfda']]
```

but i expect:

```
[[], [], [], ['sdfda'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

I want to insert elements by index...but this example of code insert the element in all list of list

Comment: do `result_list = [[] for i in range(14)]`

Comment: In short, in the line `result_list = [[]]*14`, you create 14 "references" to the same empty list, meaning that when you `append` to one, you append to all of them.

Comment: senks for explein.

Answer (score 0):

When you write [x]*3 you get, essentially, the list [x, x, x]. That is, a list with 3 references to the same x. When you then modify this single x it is visible via all three references to it.

Try this:

```
result_list = [[]]*14
result_list[3]=['sdfda']
print(result_list)
```